# making eclipse and gcc linux the same environment

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, makefile

so I have finished a big C project in eclipse and I did this by right clicking my C project folder -> properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Compiler and putting the flags

```
-c -std=c99
```

And everything is passing when I build and run my program in ECLIPSE.
Now when I move my project over to linux version:

```
[ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-10:~/Desktop/Fall_2013/MIPSAssembler]$gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

and run the following Makefile:

```
#
# Makefile to build the MIPS assembler
#
# DIRECTIONS: In the same folder that this folder is
# in type to the command line "Makefile"
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O -std=c99

OBJECTS = CUnit.o VariableVector.o preprocessor.o utilities.o parser.o assembler.o \
          variableVectorTest.o preprocessorTest.o utilitiesTest.o parserTest.o assemblerTest.o 

# Build for full program
assembler: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o assemble $(OBJECTS)

# Rules for components

CUnit.o: CUnit.c CUnit.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c CUnit.c

VariableVector.o: VariableVector.c VariableVector.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c VariableVector.c

preprocessor.o: preprocessor.c preprocessor.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c preprocessor.c

utilities.o: utilities.c utilities.h VariableVector.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c utilities.c

parser.o: parser.c parser.h utilities.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c parser.c

assembler.o: assembler.c assembler.h VariableVector.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c assembler.c

variableVectorTest.o: variableVectorTest.c variableVectorTest.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c variableVectorTest.c

preprocessorTest.o: preprocessorTest.c preprocessorTest.h CUnit.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c preprocessorTest.c

utilitiesTest.o: utilitiesTest.c utilitiesTest.h utilities.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c utilitiesTest.c

parserTest.o: parserTest.c parserTest.h VariableVector.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c parserTest.c

assemblerTest.o: assemblerTest.c assemblerTest.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c assemblerTest.c

clean:
        rm -rf *.o
```

everything compiles but when I run my tests by typing

```
./assemble // I get some seg faults!!!
```

I was wondering why is my code working in ECLIPSE but not working in LINUX running gcc and how can I make it so that my eclipse compiling  matches how I am compiling my files using gcc on linux? Thanks!

Comment: You get segmentation faults because you have errors in your program. To start with, compile with more warnings (e.g. add *at least* `-Wall` to `CFLAGS`) and rebuild. If you have warnings then fix them, they are often an indicator of *undefined behavior* which often leads to crashes. If you still have crashes then you should build with debug information (`-g` flag) and run in a debugger (e.g. GDB). It will stop when there is a crash, and let you examine and walk the call stack, as well as let you examine values of variables.

Comment: Also try running your program with `valgrind`. `valgrind` is a tool that provides a lot of additional information on many memory related bugs.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the advice. But the thing is that my program is running just fine in eclipse and since I am using the same flags I don't understand why my code is working in eclipse but not in gcc linux?

Comment: @Chingy That's the point of undefined behavior, and you can't predict it. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When you work in Eclipse, is it on e.g. Windows with Cygwin or MinGW?